# Washed colors with ffmpeg in macOs

Tags: colors, ffmpeg

I am having problems regarding the colors of a screen recorded video generated by ffmpeg on mac.

[image: Left i the original and Right i the ffmpeg generated video image]

I am using the following command to generate the video:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 1980x1140 -framerate 30 -capture_cursor 1 -capture_mouse_clicks 1 -i '1' -preset ultrafast -an -qp 0 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p  -y -c:v libx264 -c:a libfaac -vf eq=brightness=0.00:contrast=1:saturation=1 video_test.mkv
```

I tried to change `qp` to 1 and 2, to change the `crf` to 0 and 2 (let it higher and lower than qp), tried to use `pix_fmt` yuv444p and bgr0 and 0rgb, tried to change `c:v` to libx64rgb, tried to not use `vf` but the result is the same.

The only real difference I've noticed is when I put a really high crf that makes the image very pixelated...

I've tried different numbers for brightness, contrast and saturation but I couldn't find a good combination.

Any idea how to make the video look more as the original?

Full log:

[image: I've joined all the log printed by ffmpeg]

About the red message in the middle of the image, this is always printed even when I use yuv444p (the red message prints yuv420p)

Comment: Does the video look washed out when played with ffplay?

Comment: and can you post the full (uncut) output of the ffmpeg commandline used to capture and convert the screen capture? I'm guessing it's related to some part (either inside or outside ffmpeg) not interpreting the range flag correctly, the output will help analyze whether ffmpeg itself does the correct thing.

Comment: @Gyan The right image is a screenshot taken from the ffplay :(

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje I've updated my question

Comment: Add -pix_fmt <something> before the -i commandline parameter to select input color format. I'd recommend something RGB'y (0rgb or bgr0), and then use a similar RGB format as -pix_fmt parameter instead of -pix_fmt yuv420p which you have now, and use the x264rgb encoder, that should resolve the issues. Also use -v info to get logging info from swscale if it does not.

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje If I add the -pix_fmt before the -i, I get this error: `Requested output format 'avfoundation' is not a suitable output format
1: Invalid argument` and the process stops (no video). Changing the library and the other pix_fmt didn't solve the issue. I need to use the -f as avfoundation because I am on a mac and otherwise I can't record the screen...

Comment: @Gabrielle `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -pixel_format bgr0 -video_size 1980x1140 -framerate 30 -capture_cursor 1 -capture_mouse_clicks 1 -i 1 -c:v libx264rgb -preset ultrafast -crf 0 video_test.mkv`

Comment: @RonaldS.Bultje Now I don't get the error about the parameter but, the washed colors are still the same...

Comment: Not sure then. Is it reproduceable with any player? E.g. if you play with Quicktime or so, does it also look like that?

Comment: QuickPlayer can't open file. VLC plays washed colors

Answer (score 0):

Don't have any experience with avfoundation, but I had similar issue with the video conversion. Issue was caused by the HDR input. Try adding pix_fmt and x265-params as below:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt2020,format=yuv420p10 -x265-params :colorprim=9:transfer=16:colormatrix=9 -c:v libx265 -crf 26 -preset medium -acodec copy output.mp4
```